# Failed to install the OAM using the LCM during the post-configure steps，SSL error

Tags: java, weblogic, nodemanager, oracle-access-manager

So running a single node full stack installation with LCM. All goes fine till post-configure,
where the script fails trying to connect to NodeManager. It gives

```
<2022-12-6 下午08时56分54秒 CST> <Warning> <Security> <BEA-090479> <Certificate chain received from oam.com - 192.168.38.152 failed date validity checks.> 
This Exception occurred at Tue Dec 06 20:56:54 CST 2022.
javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: [Security:090479]Certificate chain received from oam.com - 192.168.38.152 failed date validity checks.
Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/u01/app/oracle/product/fmw/Oracle_IDMLCM1/provisioning/idm-provisioning-build/config/wait_for_nodemanager.py", line 13, in ?
```

Some sources suggest that I should modify the java.security file. But it didn't work.

I made a change to java.security in java_home

```
# Comment this line
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, DSA, RSA keySize \< 2048
```

And for the record, I'm using the JDK distributed with LCM. I believe it's 7u80.

Answer (score 0):

I approached this problem in several ways

1. Comment out the java.security line in JAVA_HOME
2. Make the same changes to jdk.zip in the installation directory

   ```
   #Comment this line
   jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, DSA, RSA keySize \< 2048
   ```
3. Set the system time to 20170504
4. Set system variables

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dweblogic.nodemanager.sslHostNameVerificationEnabled=false -Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=true -Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=false -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification=true"
```

I suspect the ultimate solution is to change the system time.
It's scary to run an old project

I'm even going to develop an OAM plug-in

Help!